# How to create dynamic web page in JSF-1.2 based on given PDF?

Tags: jsf, pdf, acrobat

I am looking for the solution where I can dynamically create JSF web page based on given PDF.

I can upload the PDF file (which contains text fields and check boxex) using my application and in back end a web page should be generated. Each fields of PDF should be mapped to HTML/JSF fields.

Is there any open source tool available in market that can address my above problem.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Would [ICEpdf](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf) work for you? Here's a link to an example of using it to extract text from a PDF file: http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/Extracting+Text</s>

edit: Sorry, I realize now you want to read mostly interactive fields. I haven't actually used ICEpdf for that so I will remove it for now unless someone else knows if it has that capability. Have you looked at the library [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)? The only problem is that you may run into licensing issues (it has both open source and commercial licenses depending on your purposes). There's an example on middle of this page that seems to be what you want to do: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Problem-Reading-Interactive-Form-Values-Acro-Fields-from-PDF-using-iText-td2171900.html

Comment: I walked through this..seems like this is useful to show the read only PDF. What if I have my PDF document with text fields and submit button? Will ICEpdf support this kind of PDF?

Comment: Sorry, that I am not entirely sure of. I updated my answer with another library to see if that will work for your purposes.